# table design for workflow with conditions

Tags: database, workflow, rdbms

I need to design a tables for execution flow [this may not be the right word], each step/flow will be skipped or executed based on the conditions set. user should be able to add multiple step with conditions, so based on the conditions 'next' flow/step will change.

currently we designed table like below, routing table has the link between steps, based on the conditions[runtime data], next steps will be chosen.

is it correct approach are there any standard way to design the same?, here if we want to add any new step , i need to create a new step table, is there anyway we can avoid...in some case there wont be any conditions, it is strighforward flow like from step1 to step3 then end.

[Sample DB structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oc5PL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Using database to implement workflows is a clear antipattern. I would recommend looking into [Cadence Workflow](https://cadenceworkflow.io/) that provides much higher level API and includes tons of features that you never would be able to add into your home grown ad-hoc solution.